# django template evaluating differently on firefox and safari

Tags: django, django-templates

Got the strangest problem, and it does not make sense. I have been through the code like many times and at my wits end trying to figure out what the issue is. Basically testing a site with firefox and safari, they behave differently. This may make sense for Javascript or CSS.

However, this is django code that is not evaluating differently. A simple Example:

My Template code:

```
{% if myvar == 'var1' %}   
{{ status }}
{% endif %}
```

The inclusion tag is a simple inclusion tag, that returns a few variables and updates the context.

In firefox if myvar evaluates and shows status variable. However the exact same code in safari does not work. It only works if you refresh the page (And no it's not caching as i have the dummy caching enabled)

Really this is making no sense at all! I Have it on a live testing server but cant post here. If you send me a message can send url.

Did some digging and the version that is working (Firefox) has the following additional HTTP HEADERs, while safari does not (so my guess is it does not check for the newer version)

'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE', HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH, HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE

Comment: Django creates server-side code, the templates are simply places that are being replaced before the code is output to the browser. Are you 100% sure that it's the code that is being displayed differently? Do you mind sharing other bits of your code, say views for example? We'd like to see with what context you're rendering the template.

Comment: Maybe safari is using cache that is only reloading when you force it to?

Comment: @kvshenin, thanks, i understand that it's server side code and delivered to the browser. Which is why it does not make sense to me. Django knows nothing about browsers. It generates the html to deliver to the browser. Hence i said does not make sense.

Comment: @nate c, that could possibly it (browser side caching), but why is it doing this in safari and not firefox. I also tested on other browsers and sometimes it does and sometimes not (usually when the browser is based on webkit)

Comment: @kovshenin, not sure how to put extra code in as there is a lot of stuff happening for that particular bit of fucntionality. i.e i am using an external lib, with my own inclusion code etc. Custom view, been through all the code. However let me go through it once again and will post here sample code.

Comment: @izzy, did you try setting no pragma:cache-control:no-cache on your page (or in your server). Making web sites cross-browser compatible is a real PITA in my experience :/

Answer (score 0):

Is `myvar` something you harvested from a URL?  Perhaps Firefox and Safari are sending slightly different strings?

Comment: Nop, my var is passed in as a context variable. Which is why i am totally lost on this one (It makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have a context processor and/or middleware that is mucking with things? Both of those can create weird man-behind-the-curtain type problems -- sort of like having networking problem and not knowing that there's a firewall munching on your packets.